# Remote Docker Port forwarding

Tags: docker, server, pycharm

I have trouble in visiting my remote docker.

I have a remote server machine which has been forwarded on the port for visiting in public Internet. So I can visit this remote server by SSH connection with the address XX.XX.XX.XX:18022.

18022 is the forwarding port corresponding to the ssh port 22.

But when I build a Docker container in this server, how can I debugger my program in that docker by PyCharm?

I think that I can't access my docker absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

I can solve it by building docker with host model, so I can visit docker absolutely.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can open your docker rest api port to your workstation, and it work to me.